# Trying to inject a bean with @Required annotation but getting nullpointer

Tags: java, spring-mvc

This is my `Web.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>loungeHotel</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/loungeHotel.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my `loungeHotel.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd     
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


<bean id = "updateProfileDao"  class="com.lounge.dao.impl.UpdateProfileDaoImpl"></bean>

<bean id = "updateProfileFacade"  class="com.lounge.facades.impl.UserProfileFacadeImpl">
    <property name="updateProfileDao" ref="updateProfileDao"></property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

**this is the java file(`UserProfileFacadeImpl.java`) where i want to use my bean (`updateProfileDao`)**

```
package com.lounge.facades.impl;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Required;

import com.lounge.dao.impl.UpdateProfileDaoImpl;
import com.lounge.dataModels.StudentData;
import com.lounge.facade.UserProfileFacade;

public class UserProfileFacadeImpl implements UserProfileFacade {

    @Resource(name="updateProfileDao")
    private UpdateProfileDaoImpl updateProfileDao;


    public UpdateProfileDaoImpl getUpdateProfileDao() {
        return updateProfileDao;
    }

    @Required
    public void setUpdateProfileDao(UpdateProfileDaoImpl updateProfileDao) {
        this.updateProfileDao = updateProfileDao;
    }
    @Override
    public StudentData updateProfile(StudentData studentData,String name){
        return getUpdateProfileDao().updateColumn(studentData, name);
    }
}
```

**here is stacktrace...**

```
>org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

>java.lang.**NullPointerException**
    com.lounge.facades.impl.UserProfileFacadeImpl.updateProfile(UserProfileFacadeImpl.java:30)
    com.lounge.controllers.AccountPageController.updateProfile(AccountPageController.java:63)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: He knows what an NPE is. What he doesn't know is why his bean does not get injected.

Comment: i think its different , when i am creating a object with new keyword its working fine but when creating a bean in Xml file and then using that bean in my java file using @Required annotation then it's giving null pointer

Comment: go to UserProfileFacadeImpl.java:30

Comment: Post the code for your controller class.

Comment: How did you access UserProfileFacadeImpl ? Is this Autowired or not?

Comment: public static StudentData updateProfile(
   @ModelAttribute("student1") StudentData student1,
   final Model model, HttpSession session) {

  UserProfileFacade userProfileFacade = new UserProfileFacadeImpl();
  StudentData student = (StudentData) session.getAttribute("student");
  
  StudentData studentObj = userProfileFacade.updateProfile(student1 ,student.getName());
return studentObj ;
}

Comment: @fuzzy28 :- i am using new operator for that

Comment: if you create an instance of UserProfileFacadeImpl  using the new operator, you are explicitly not using spring to create your object.  This means that spring is not managing the object you created, so none of the Spring annotations matter.  Final result: no spring == no injection

Answer (score 0):

Here actually `@Resource` doesn't matter as you're explicitly setting the property in the xml.

I assume the root cause is rather in the controller, most probably the object is instantiated directly instead of being injected by application container.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using SpringMVC I would recommend use @Autowired to load your Dao as service instead of using @Resource

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you are accessing UserProfileFacadeImpl via `new` operator. This defeats the purpose of dependency injection and the reason why you are encountering a NPE. UserProfileFacadeImpl should be accessed by getting it in Spring container.

Answer (score 0):

Add a bean of type **UserProfileFacadeImpl** to your spring configuration file (loungeHotel.xml).

Inject this bean instead of calling new.